# Is$ \int_{0}^{\pi} f^{2}(x) d x$ divergent or convergent?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis

let be $f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin n x}{n^{2 / 3}}$

Find $\int_{0}^{\pi} f^{2}(x) d x$

I have understood that $\quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (n t)}{n^{2 / 3}} d t=\int_{0}^{\pi} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sin (n t)}{n^{2 / 3}} d t$

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sin (n t)}{n^{2 / 3}} d t = \frac{1-\cos (\pi n)}{n^{5 / 3}} \Rightarrow \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) d x = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1-\cos (\pi n)}{n^{5 / 3}}$$

But it's all that I can

Comment: Have you seen Parseval's theorem?

Comment: No. Maybe this will help in solving the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functions $\sin nx$ form an orthogonal system in $L^2(0,\pi)$ and $||\sin nx||^2=\pi/2$.. If we write $S(x)=\sum a_n \sin nx$ then $\sum |a_n|^2=\sum n^{-4/3}<\infty$ hence the infinite sum converges in $L^2$. In fact we have $\int S^2 dx=||S||^2=(\pi/2) \sum_1^\infty  {1\over {n^{4/3}}}$ by Parseval.